# JSON loads returning string

Tags: python, json, encoding

I have the following code:

```
url = 'https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/SPY'
result = requests.get(url)

c = result.content
html = BeautifulSoup(c, 'html.parser')
scripts = html.find_all('script')

sl =[]
for s in scripts:

     sl.append(s)

s = (sl[-3])
s = s.contents
s = str(s)
s = s[119:-16]
s = json.dumps(s)
json_data = json.loads(s)
```

Once I check the data type for json_data I get a string. I am assuming that there are potentially some text encoding errors in the json data and it cannot properly be recognized as a json object.

However when I try dumping the data into a file and entering it into an online json parser, the parser can read the json data properly and recognize keys and values.

How can I fix this so that I can properly access the data within the json object?

Comment: You take a string, `dump` it and `load` it, and it will be a string again.

Comment: You shouldn't dump the string, you should dump the list. Then when you load it, you'll get another list.

Comment: Are you trying to parse a JavaScript literal that's inside the script? Then don't call `json.dumps()` at all. `s` should be the JSON you want to load from.

Comment: Note, however, that JSON is a very restricted form of JavaScript syntax. Many literals in JS code will not be recognized by a JSON parser. JSON only allows doublequotes, not singlequotes, and requires all object keys to be quoted.

Comment: If I just load it I get the following error: json.decoder.JSONDecodError: Expecting ',' delimiter: line 1 column 7484 (char 7484 )

Comment: That's what I'm talking about. JSON is derived from JavaScript, but it's much more limited.

Comment: But then how do i parse the JavaScript literal ?

Answer (score 1):

You have to change `[119:-16]` into `[112:-12]` and you can get json as dictionary

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import json

url = 'https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/SPY'
result = requests.get(url)

html = BeautifulSoup(result.content, 'html.parser')
script = html.find_all('script')[-3].text
data = script[112:-12]

json_data = json.loads(data)

print(type(json_data))
#print(json_data)
print(json_data.keys())
print(json_data['context'].keys())
print(json_data['context']['dispatcher']['stores']['PageStore']['currentPageName'])
```

Result:

```
<class 'dict'>
dict_keys(['context', 'plugins'])
dict_keys(['dispatcher', 'options', 'plugins'])
quote
```